# Automating deploying changes to website via FTP (Mercurial is used)

Tags: php, deployment, mercurial

We have a website consisting of thousands of files and we need to upload changes (between revisions X and Y) to different hosting servers via FTP. Some of our websites are on shared hosting and we want a universal solution, that is why we need to use FTP, because it's supported everywhere.

1) I don't want all files to be uploaded, only the changed ones.
2) I don't want every file on remote FTP server to be checked to determine if it needs to be updated - it will be too long, because as I said - we have thousands of files.

So I want my deployment workflow to be like this:

1) I know that the website in production is of revision X.
2) I want to update it to revision Y (which is X+10, for example)
3) So I choose that I want all files changed between revisions X and Y to be copied to a specified folder on FTP server.
4) Would be very nice if I could choose files to exclude (such as hosting.specific.php config which contains database connection data, etc.)

If there is no such tool that could do all of this for me, then at least I would like to find a tool that can get changed files from Mercurial and copy them to any other folder (presuming folder structure), and then I would manually copy that folder to FTP server.

Comment: Have you tried [FTPSync](http://www.cyberkiko.com/page/FTPSync.aspx)? I used it and was very happy with it.

Comment: Perhaps use a [post-commit-hook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) to generate changesets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the HgExportFiles extension: https://bitbucket.org/albert_brand/hgexportfiles/wiki/Home